# Installing HDF5

Tags: software-installation

I'm very new to Ubuntu, like really new, but I need to install the HDF5 library. However, when I follow general steps in tutorials for installation of packages, it goes to using the config file, which I just can't find anywhere in the downloaded package.

I need to install this version of the library: https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/releases/hdf5-1.8/hdf5-1.8.10/obtain51810.html

I think I should be using the static one for a 64-bit system.

I would be very grateful for any tips

Comment: What "general steps in tutorials for installation of packages" are you referring to, exactly? The archive files in your link appear to contain *binary packages* so ignore any tutorials that are for the installation of software from source code.

Comment: @simonblaha please narrow your use case. The below answer is already useful, but I can edit it to suite your needs.

Comment: @N0rbert I need it for running Flash, however the latest version that the code in my repositories is compatible with is the 1.8.10, which is very outdated

Answer (score 1):

To compile the exact version HDF5 1.8.10 version you need old Ubuntu version such as 14.04 LTS (now EOL).
At first enable source code *deb-src* repositories from Software & Updates (`software-properties-gtk`).

Then execute the below commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
sudo apt-get build-dep hdf5

mkdir ~/Software
cd ~/Software
wget https://support.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/releases/hdf5-1.8/hdf5-1.8.10/src/hdf5-1.8.10.tar.gz
tar -xf hdf5-1.8.10.tar.gz
cd hdf5-1.8.10/
./configure
make -j9
sudo make install
```

and then try to include this library to your program. To remove the locally compiled HDF5 library visit the `~/Software/hdf5-1.8.10/` and then run `sudo make uninstall` here.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a way to specify the version of the library being installed?

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, then you will get HDF5 1.10 from the official repository by using above commands. What is your use-case? Should I add something more to the above answer?

Comment: I'll be using it for running Flash Simulations, however, the code in the repositories I should use is compatible with the HDF libraries of version 1.8.10, so 1.10 won't work.

Comment: I think you can easily configure Docker container with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (HDF 1.8.11) or 16.04 LTS (1.8.16).